# jBPM Library folder not showing for new jBPM Eclipse projects

Tags: jbpm

I installed jBPM 6.4 using the installer on Windows. The `Runtime` folder was created and the Eclipse `Installed jBPM Runtimes` seems to be properly configured but when a new `jBPM project` is created in Eclipse the `jBPM Library` folder doesn't show. [However, the `jBPM Library` folder does show when the included sample project 'evaluation' is imported into Eclipse.]

How do I get the `jBPM Library` folder to show in Eclipse for new jBPM projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the project, uncheck the "maven project" checkbox, this will let you use the jBPM library instead of maven (when using maven for dependencies it doesn't really make sense to also include jBPM library).

Comment: Thanks Kris, Really appreciate the help. btw, based on your answer to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582233/jbpm-maven-dependencies-not-showing-in-pom-xml) I upgraded the plugin which makes the Maven/jBPM library distinction explicit.