# jBPM Maven dependencies not showing in pom.xml

Tags: jbpm

When I create a new jBPM project in Eclipse and select `Create as Maven Project` the pom.xml is generated without the dependency section. While I can manually add the dependencies,  shouldn't the plugin do this automatically? Am I missing something?

Comment: You should check the effective pom to see if dependencies are truly missing or they're set somewhere else

Comment: Thanks, but I checked and the effective pom is missing it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using 6.4.0.Final?  There were issues with that version of the Eclipse wizard, that should be fixed in the following update site:
http://downloads.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.1.Final/updatesite/